# possible to change build directory in jwrapper?

Tags: jwrapper

when I use ANT to invoke the jwrapper task, is there a possibility to (re-)define the build directory ?

jwrapper uses automatically "build" and this collides with the existing build task and folder structure...

Thank you!
Peter

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution by using the "dir" attribute of the java ant task

```
<mkdir dir="${basedir}/build_jwrapper"/>


<java jar="${JWrapperJAR}" failonerror="true" fork="true"
    dir="${basedir}/build_jwrapper">
    <jvmarg value="-Xmx512m"/>
    <arg value="${basedir}/jwrapper.xml"/>
</java>
```